# Haproxy - ACL rules for post requests

Tags: haproxy

I would like to deny the access to a rest api endpoint if a specific query string parameter (e.g. param) is set in a post request.

E.g.: `POST /api?param`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following ACL role to your HA Proxy configuration:

```
acl param_in_url query -i param
http-request deny if param_in_url
```